# How to adjust how a mesh looks in-between shape keys?

Tags: shape-keys

I'm just learning about shape keys. I created two shape keys, the basis one and one with the tip of the finger bent. I added the bone of the tip of the finger as a driver. It works but, the changes I made so that the bent finger looks better make it so that when it's going back to its original shape it doesn't look quite right. How can I edit the in-between shape?

[image]

Comment: If you need more info to help me let know.

Answer (score 2):

Shapekeys are not a very solid alternative to rigging. The way shapekeys work is by exclusively translating each vertex from the Basis to the shapekey. The shortest way to do this would be by translating each vertex in the way you see in your "in-between". Shapekeys should only be used for things such as facial expressions, correcting armature deforms, etc.  In short, the inbetweens cannot be controlled, you're going to have to rig that finger if you want it to move correctly

Comment: It is rigged. The whole character is, using riggify. It just never looks that great when you do a closed fist. I thought shape keys would help me make it look better. Someone in a different forum helped me and you can edit the curves for the shape key drivers and it definitely helps.I'm still learning though.